# Grails springSecurity reload authorities without relogin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 3.3.5 and org.grails.plugins:spring-security-acl:3.2.1.

Is there any way to easily rebuild Authentication (including authorities) for non-current user on fly?

The issue is the following: admin grants user a role, but the role is taken into account only after user's relogin.

Is there any analogue like springSecurityService.reauthenticate(...) but for non-current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, unless you replace the default http session mechanism with some centralized cache, allowing the admin to change session attributes for any arbitrary user on the fly.

Comment: Well, you could approach it another way. You could create some filter/interceptor that checks to see if a username is registered with it and need to have it's authorities reloaded.Then every request filters through it, if the current user making the request is the one the admin modified and placed into this it would trigger reloading for that user. You could do this and not have to mess with any of the defaults (as you suggested).

Comment: you still need a centralized storage to access from the interceptor

Comment: An in memory synchronized map would work, in the simplest case.

Comment: yep, unless you have a load-balanced cluster

Comment: Agreed, then you'd have to use something that's not the "simplest case". Still not nearly as complex as replacing default http session mechanism.